# c# Asynchronous methods Webclient exception

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm having a problem with my acynchronous method:

I'm getting this Error

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: The thread got aborted.
       at System.Net.NetworkInformation.UnsafeNetInfoNativeMethods.GetNetworkParams(SafeLocalFree pFixedInfo, UInt32& pOutBufLen)
       bei System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemIPGlobalProperties.GetFixedInfo()
       bei System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemIPGlobalProperties.get_FixedInfo()
       bei System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemIPGlobalProperties.get_HostName()
       bei System.Net.NclUtilities.GuessWhetherHostIsLoopback(String host)
       bei System.Net.ServicePoint.get_ConnectionLimit()
       bei System.Net.ConnectionGroup..ctor(ServicePoint servicePoint, String connName)
       bei System.Net.ServicePoint.FindConnectionGroup(String connName, Boolean dontCreate)
       bei System.Net.ServicePoint.SubmitRequest(HttpWebRequest request, String connName)
       bei System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SubmitRequest(ServicePoint servicePoint)
       bei System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       bei System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
       bei System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream, CompletionDelegate completionDelegate, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
       bei System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
       bei System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
       bei System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)
       bei TwitchAccountCreator.Classes.ProxyScaperAndTester.ProxyScraper.ScrapeFreeList1() in d:\Simon\TeamFoundation\TwitchTV Account Creator\TwitchAccountCreator\TwitchAccountCreator\Classes\ProxyScaperAndTester\ProxyScraper.cs:Zeile 86.
       bei UnitTestProject1.ProxyScraperTestClass.<ProxyScraper>b__2(Object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args) in d:\Simon\TeamFoundation\TwitchTV Account Creator\TwitchAccountCreator\UnitTestProject1\UnitTest2.cs:Zeile 18.
       bei TwitchAccountCreator.Classes.ProxyScaperAndTester.ProxyScraper.OnUnhandledException(Exception ex, Boolean terminating) in d:\Simon\TeamFoundation\TwitchTV Account Creator\TwitchAccountCreator\TwitchAccountCreator\Classes\ProxyScaperAndTester\ProxyScraper.cs:Zeile 39.
       bei TwitchAccountCreator.Classes.ProxyScaperAndTester.ProxyScraper.ScrapeFreeList1() in d:\Simon\TeamFoundation\TwitchTV Account Creator\TwitchAccountCreator\TwitchAccountCreator\Classes\ProxyScaperAndTester\ProxyScraper.cs:Zeile 93.
       bei TwitchAccountCreator.Classes.ProxyScaperAndTester.ProxyScraper.ScrapeProxies() in d:\Simon\TeamFoundation\TwitchTV Account Creator\TwitchAccountCreator\TwitchAccountCreator\Classes\ProxyScaperAndTester\ProxyScraper.cs:Zeile 53.
       bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
       bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)
       bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.AgileAsyncWorkerItem.ThreadPoolCallBack(Object o)
       bei System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
       bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       bei System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
       bei System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
       bei System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

The function works fine if I call it synchronous. The functions are:

```
public void ScrapeProxiesAsync()
    {
        ScrapeProxiesDelegate worker = new ScrapeProxiesDelegate(ScrapeProxies);
        AsyncOperation async = AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation(null);
        worker.BeginInvoke(null, null);
    }

    private void ScrapeProxies()
    {
        var proxyList = new List<string>();
        proxyList.AddRange(ScrapeFreeList1());
        OnProgressChanged(proxyList.Count, 20);
        proxyList.AddRange(ScrapeFreeList2());
        OnProgressChanged(proxyList.Count, 40);
        proxyList.AddRange(ScrapeFreeList3());
        OnProgressChanged(proxyList.Count, 60);
        proxyList.AddRange(ScrapeFreeList4());
        OnProgressChanged(proxyList.Count, 80);
        proxyList.AddRange(ScrapeFreeList5());
        OnProgressChanged(proxyList.Count, 100);
        var removeDupProxies = proxyList.Distinct().ToList();
        OnScrapinComplete(removeDupProxies);
    }

private List<string> ScrapeFreeList1()
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            string source = client.DownloadString("http://free-proxy-list.net/");
            var matches = Regex.Matches(source, @"(?<=tr><td>)(.*\d<?)(?=</td>)");
            return (from object match in matches select match.ToString().Replace("</td><td>", ":")).ToList();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        OnUnhandledException(ex, false);
        return new List<string>();
    }
}
```

My Unit testing class for this is:

```
        [TestMethod]
    public void ProxyScraper()
    {
        ProxyScraper pc = new ProxyScraper();
        pc.OnProgressChangedHandler += (sender, args) => Debug.WriteLine(args.Progress + " - " + args.ScrapedProxies);
        pc.OnScrapingCompleteHandler += (sender, args) => Debug.WriteLine(args.ScrapedProxies.Count);
        pc.OnUnhandledExceptionHandler += (sender, args) => Debug.Fail(args.ExceptionObject.ToString());
        pc.ScrapeProxiesAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("Async Scraping started");
    }
```

I actually have no idea why this thread gets aborted!

Comment: Can you please point out the specific line where the error occurs in your code instead of dumping the entire stack trace?

Comment: @Asad I can't! I found out that it's an error with the unit testing framework! It's a bug!